# How to override a service

Tags: symfony-services, message-subscribe

I am trying to override a service by using a ServiceProvider Class

```
class MyModuleServiceProvider extends ServiceProviderBase
{
    public function alter(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        // Overrides MessageNotifier class to add loggin facilities to each message.
        $definition = $container->getDefinition('message_notify.sender');
        $definition->setClass('Drupal\my_module\MyModuleMessageNotifier')->addArgument([
            new Reference('logger.channel.message_notify')
        ]);
    }
}
```

This is out of topic, but FYI, the overrode service "message_notify.sender" is created by the message_notify module pertaining to the message stack modules

As you can see, I am adding an argument (a logger) to my new service

Here is the `__construct()` method of the **parent** (overrode) class:

```
  public function __construct(Manager $notifier_manager) {
    $this->notifierManager = $notifier_manager;
  }
```

Here is the `__construct()` method of my new class:

```
    public function __construct(Manager $notifier_manager, LoggerChannelInterface $logger)
    {
        parent::__construct($notifier_manager);
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }
```

But for an unknown reason the $logger variable is not an object but an array with one item... and this item is the LoggerChannel object.

Thus this code is not working but the following does:

```
    public function __construct(Manager $notifier_manager, array $logger)
    {
        parent::__construct($notifier_manager);
        $this->logger = $logger[0];
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding your argument as an array, so your `__construct()` method receives an array. So this:

```
$definition->setClass('Drupal\my_module\MyModuleMessageNotifier')->addArgument([
  new Reference('logger.channel.message_notify')
]);
```

Should be this:

```
$definition->setClass('Drupal\my_module\MyModuleMessageNotifier')
  ->addArgument(new Reference('logger.channel.message_notify'));
```

(notice that the Reference is not wrapped in an array.

Comment: I feel realy stupid... many thanks Jaypan for your help!!!

Comment: Nothing to feel stupid about. We've all been there - sometimes you just need another set of eyes.